# How to get a list of all hosts specified by ansible-playbook --limit

Tags: ansible

### The situation

I have a playbook whose execution I sometimes want to limit to specific hosts: web servers and application servers, e.g., `--limit mywebserver, appserver1, appserver2`. I have two groups:

- `webservers` contain web servers including `mywebserver`
- `appservers` contain application servers including `appserver1` and `appserver2`

The **playbook** calls a play that I call for each of my webservers:

```
- name: Install and prepare Webservers
  hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - role: webserver_setup
```

In that **play**, I execute tasks, e.g., setting up a website for each application server that is stored in a group variable:

```
- name: Configure website for all application servers
  notify: Reload webserver
  loop: "{{ groups['webserver_' + inventory_hostname] }}"
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: ./templates/website.y2
    dest: "/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ hostvars[item]['app_server'] }}.conf"
    mode: '0640'
    owner: webserver
    group: webserver
```

That works fine if I run the script without `--limit`. However, if I specify a host for `--limit`, then the loop in the play is still executed for all application servers, because it doesn't take the limit option into account. (No surprise here.)

### My question

My problem is that I have a lot of application servers, and that I would like to limit the play's loop to only the hosts specified by `--limit`. How'd I do that?

### Thoughts on solutions

- There are special variables provided by Ansible, `ansible_play_hosts`, `ansible_play_batch`, but they only provide the hosts limited by `--limit` for the current play. In my case, these variables would contain only `mywebserver`, because the play is called for `hosts: webservers`.
- I've thought about refactoring the play, such that it is called for each application server, instead, and use `delegate_to` to actually execute the task above on each associated webserver. However, I think this would have some drawbacks (ssh log in overhead for each app server, reload webserver config overhead for each app server, possible conflicts due to parallel task execution on the web server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ansible_limit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) provides the limit that was passed on the command line, and can be expanded into a list of hostnames using the [`inventory_hostnames`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/inventory_hostnames_lookup.html) lookup. You could just use this in a condition; it's not entirely clear from the question what your actual structure is, but one of the following is probably right:

```yaml
  when: item in query('inventory_hostnames', ansible_limit | default('all'))
# OR
  when: hostvars[item]['app_server'] in query('inventory_hostnames', ansible_limit | default('all'))
```

You might also be able to eliminate items from the loop entirely, though that makes the code a bit more complex and it's helpful to use intermediate variables to make it more readable:

```yaml
- name: Configure website for all application servers
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: website.y2  # Relative paths in template actions use `templates/` automatically, so you shouldn't specify it.
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ hostvars[item]['app_server'] }}.conf
    mode: "0640"
    owner: webserver
    group: webserver
  notify: Reload webserver
  loop: "{{ webserver_group | intersect(limit_hosts) }}"
  vars:
    webserver_group: "{{ groups['webserver_' ~ inventory_hostname] }}"
    limit_hosts: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', ansible_limit | default('all')) }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for! Also, I wasn't aware of inventory_hostnames - got some food for reading documentation.